# Abstract method with generic type

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to make that:
[image: My model]

I'm little confused. I want to make a function called **Update(T other)**, that the parameter "other" type is the class type. I think, with a generic interface implemented in abstract class it will work, but it does not work. :/

How can I get an abstract method with a generic type parameter, and specify that type in the inherited classes? Is that possible? Is my approach correct?

**Code:**

```
public interface IUpdateable<T>
{
    void Update(T pOther);
}

public abstract class Instruction_Template : IUpdateable<Instruction_Template>
{
    public abstract void Update(??? pOther);
}

public class Work_Instruction_Template : Instruction_Template
{
    public void Update(Work_Instruction_Template pOther)
    {
       //logic...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, wouldn't be better to provide a code sample rather than an UML diagram? ;P

Answer (score 2):

Using [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
abstract class Instruction_TP<T> 
    where T : Instruction_TP<T>
{
    public abstract void Update(T instruction);
}

class Process_Instruction_TP : Instruction_TP<Process_Instruction_TP>
{
    public override void Update(Process_Instruction_TP instruction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

abstract class NC_Instruction_TP<T> : Instruction_TP<T>
    where T : NC_Instruction_TP<T>
{ }

class Drill_Instruction_TP : NC_Instruction_TP<Drill_Instruction_TP>
{
    public override void Update(Drill_Instruction_TP instruction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use that, can I iterate a collection with foreach? something like

foreach(Instruction_TP current in List<Instruction_TP>)

Comment: @Maik You can add an interface like `IUpdateable` with no generics, and put all your instances in a `List<IUpdatable>`.

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem?

```
public interface IstructionTP<T>
    where T : class
{
    void Update(T entity);
}

public class ProcessIstructionTP : IstructionTP<ProcessIstructionTP>
{
    public void Update(ProcessIstructionTP entity) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```